# Is ApplePay certificate compatible with Microsoft IIS 10?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, applepay

One of our clients are currently using Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) 10 for certificate management, but for Apple Pay, the certificate(.cer) is generated by Apple, not the client. I'd like to know if the certificate issued by Apple can be imported and installed in Microsoft IIS 10.

Comment: .cer certificate issued by apple can be imported into IIS. You can go to IIS manager->server certificates->complete certificiate request -> select your .cer file and input friendly name.

Comment: "for certificate management", what kind of management? IIS does not manage certificates at all. Do you mean AD Certificate Services? The Apple Pay certificate doesn't seem to be a "Server Certificate" for web servers, https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devb2e62b839?sub=devf31990e3f So I don't think you can import it in IIS 10.